# WIFI 6E with 6GHz - Ubuntu 22.04 not able to connect

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

I am facing a problem in connection to my dedicated 6 GHz network. In the past I did an upgraded to the newest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS kernel version to get a valide firmware. After that I can see all needed channels including 2,4/5/6 GHz now, like it should:

```
root@cloud:/etc# iw reg get
global 
phy#0 (self-managed)
country DE: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2437 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40MINUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2422 - 2462 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (2447 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 22), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-HT40PLUS, NO-80MHZ, NO-160MHZ
    (5170 - 5190 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5190 - 5210 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5210 - 5230 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5230 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    ...
    ...
    (6325 - 6345 @ 480), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (6345 - 6365 @ 480), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (6365 - 6385 @ 480), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (6385 - 6405 @ 480), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40PLUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (6405 - 6425 @ 480), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN
```

So at the first look the configs seems to be fine. I am running on kernel **6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu** with **core72**. If I try to connect to 2.4/5 GHz everything works as expected:

```
root@cloud:/etc# wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp2s0
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
wlp2s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with e4:38:83:43:62:fa (SSID='J.A.R.V.I.S.' freq=5200 MHz)
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with e4:38:83:43:62:fa (SSID='J.A.R.V.I.S.' freq=5200 MHz)
wlp2s0: Associated with e4:38:83:43:62:fa
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlp2s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with e4:38:83:43:62:fa [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to e4:38:83:43:62:fa completed [id=0 id_str=]
...
^Cp2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=e4:38:83:43:62:fa reason=3 locally_generated=1
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

But if I try to connect to my dedicated 6 GHz network the connection building stucks:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=WORLD
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
...    
^Cp2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

So need your help to figure out, what is the root cause of this "non-connecting".

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile I found the solution with another specialist. It seems that "wpa_supplicant" do not automatically use WPA3 with 6 GHz network and tried to use WPA/WPA2 which doesn't work on that channeling.

So I changed my configuration to the minimum needed parts:

```
root@cloud:/# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
        ssid="<my network>"
        key_mgmt=SAE
        sae_password="<my password>"
        ieee80211w=2
}
```